# Cumulative returns by group and moving window (Momentum strategies)

Tags: pandas, group-by, moving-average

I want to compute a momentum strategy using lagged compounded returns grouped by ID in a moving window setting.  I have tried the following code on other attributes (sum, mean, skew and Kurt) and it works well. However, cumulative product and product doesn't seem to be implemented.

```
df=df.set_index('date') 
df['mom_1Y']=df.groupby('id')['dailyreturn'].apply(lambda x: (x.rolling(251, min_periods=22).cumprod())
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "/Users/mcdo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 273, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(

AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'cumprod'
```

edit with data example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':np.repeat(range(100), 10),
    'dailyreturn':np.random.randn(1000),  
    'date':np.random.choice(pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=12,freq='M'), 1000, replace=True)})
```

Comment: maybe the .cumprod() needs to be outside the parenthesis, or even outside the apply(). It operates on the series (based on the docs), so you may just be trying to use it too early in the calculations. Can you post a small dataset to test?

Comment: Thank you for the response Jonathan. I added a data example into the post. I tried also  with .transform() and simple .rolling() methods without luck. I got similar error messages (AttributeError: 'RollingGroupby' object has no attribute 'cumprod')

Comment: maybe i'm misunderstanding. you want the cumprod of the grouping or cumprod of the rolling(sum)? rolling(mean)? etc? i think if you want to use cumprod you have to use sum(), mean() etc. first or just cumprod without rolling. like x.cumprod()

Comment: both of these return results. df.groupby('id')['dailyreturn'].apply(lambda x: (x.rolling(10, min_periods=3).sum())).cumprod()  
df.groupby('id')['dailyreturn'].apply(lambda x: (x.cumprod()))